# Using DAX, how do I calculate a table when filtering on a related table?

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerpivot, dax, ssas-tabular

I'm trying to find the intersect of two result sets using DAX, but I'm really struggling to get the two result sets calculated.

I have a fact table, FactCheckForUpdates, that has a relationship to a date table called 'Log Date'.  FactCheckForUpdates contains Machine IDs, and I want to return the IDs for the last 2 complete months.

I can calculate the distinct count of Machine IDs using this formula:

```
2Month Distinct Machines:=CALCULATE (
    [Distinct Machine Ids], 
    FILTER( 
        ALL( 'Log Date' ), 
        ( 'Log Date'[YearMonthNumber] >= MAX( 'Log Date'[YearMonthNumber] ) - 3 ) 
        && ( 'Log Date'[YearMonthNumber] <= MAX( 'Log Date'[YearMonthNumber] ) - 1 )
    )
)
```

Where 'Distinct Machine Ids' is calculated as:

```
:=DISTINCTCOUNT([MachineId])
```

and where 'YearMonthNumber' is calculated on the 'Log Date' table as:

```
=('Log Date'[YearKey] - MIN('Log Date'[YearKey])) * 12 + 'Log Date'[MonthOfYearKey]
```

(effectively this gives the number of the month in the context of the entire date dimension).

**Can anyone help me update the [2Month Distinct Machines] expression so that instead of returning the distinct count of Machine IDs in the period, it returns a table of the machine IDs?**

I've tried using the CALCULATETABLE function, but it won't accept the MAX aggregate on the date filter.  The closest I've gotten is this formula:

```
CALCULATETABLE (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( FactCheckForUpdates, FactCheckForUpdates[MachineId] ),
        "meh", CALCULATE ( SUM ( FactCheckForUpdates[CFUPing] ) )
    ),
    FactCheckForUpdates[LogDateKey] > DATE ( 2016, 4, 1 )
)
```

but I'm not sure how to use the 'Log Date' table here.

Any help massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
CALCULATETABLE (
    VALUES(FactCheckForUpdates[MachineId]), 
    FILTER( 
        ALL( 'Log Date' ), 
        ( 'Log Date'[YearMonthNumber] >= MAX( 'Log Date'[YearMonthNumber] ) - 3 ) 
        && ( 'Log Date'[YearMonthNumber] <= MAX( 'Log Date'[YearMonthNumber] ) - 1 )
    )
)
```

Where are you calling this DAX expression from? It's only going to work inside another expression or as part of a query.

Comment: Thanks Greg - I've tried your suggestion, but it returns 0 rows.  I think that is possibly due to the CALCULATETABLE function ignoring context.

I'll use the expression inside another, basically I want to get two tables of machine IDs, then find the intersect of them and return the row count of intersecting values.  Simplified form would be something like:
`CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( INTERSECT ( <CalculatedTableA>, <CalculatedTableB> ) ) )`

Comment: Actually, trying your suggestion outside of DaxStudio and in my model did actually work - my bad!